# Existence of Morse function on suspension

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology, morse-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth simply connected compact manifold of dimension $n$ with boundary. Let $Y$ be a smooth compact manifold of dimension $n+1$ without boundary such that $H_{i+1}(Y)=H_{i}(X)$(reduced singular homology). Then is it true that there exists a Morse function on $Y$ with exactly two critical points with indexes $n+1$? If not under what assumption on $Y$ such Morse function exists on $Y$?
My intuition behind the above question is that 2nd projection of suspension of $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ seems to be a Morse function with above property.

Comment: I think suspensions are rarely manifolds.

Comment: yes that is true but there could be smooth manifolds which has same homotopy type of the suspension. My question really is about existence of morse function with certain property on the homotopic smooth manifold and if someone can say something about those kind of manifolds it would be helpful too. Thanks

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ closed? If so, Poincaré duality implies that $X$ and $Y$ are rational homology spheres.

Comment: actually what I need is for non compact open manifold. I am editing my question. Thanks a lot for your comment

Comment: On non compact manifolds you want to add a conditionlike properness. Otherwise anything is possible

Comment: I have reduced my manifold to be compact manifolds with boundary@Thomas. Thanks